# Getting all the information from Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK in my Android App. What I need is to get all the information of the user including the Name, Email, Birthday, Location. But all I can get is the Name and Email. Is there any permission to get the Birthday and Location? I also look at this link but if not working for me  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/.

Here is my way of getting the information.

```
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);

                JSONObject obj = null;
                URL img = null;


                try {
                    String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                    obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
                    String id = obj.optString("id");
                    String name = obj.optString("name");
                    String bday = obj.optString("birthday");
                String address = obj.optString("location");
                    String email = obj.optString("email");
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText("Welcome! "+name);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbday)).setText("Birthday: "+bday);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress)).setText("Address: "+address);
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtemail)).setText("Email: "+email);
                    img = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=normal");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


this is my authorized

fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email", "user_location", "user_birthday","publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
                }

                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    updateButtonImage();
                }

                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

this is what log says

```
11-14 14:05:40.399: E/Trace(1293): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-14 14:05:41.699: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 290K, 6% free 6173K/6535K, paused 71ms+76ms, total 201ms
11-14 14:05:42.509: I/Choreographer(1293): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:05:42.519: D/gralloc_goldfish(1293): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-14 14:05:42.679: I/Choreographer(1293): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I also got this one from my log cat

```
11-14 14:19:28.339: D/AndroidRuntime(1359): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-14 14:19:28.339: D/AndroidRuntime(1359): CheckJNI is ON
11-14 14:19:28.379: D/dalvikvm(1359): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:28.389: D/dalvikvm(1359): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:28.409: D/dalvikvm(1359): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:28.409: D/dalvikvm(1359): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:29.059: D/AndroidRuntime(1359): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-14 14:19:29.089: W/ActivityManager(146): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/facebook.apk
11-14 14:19:29.119: W/ActivityManager(146): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/facebook.apk
11-14 14:19:29.249: I/PackageManager(146): Removing non-system package:com.example.facebook
11-14 14:19:29.249: I/ActivityManager(146): Force stopping package com.example.facebook uid=10054
11-14 14:19:29.249: I/ActivityManager(146): Killing proc 1339:com.example.facebook/u0a54: force stop
11-14 14:19:29.249: W/ActivityManager(146): Force removing ActivityRecord{411f5b90 com.example.facebook/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
11-14 14:19:29.279: I/WindowState(146): WIN DEATH: Window{41263720 com.example.facebook/com.example.facebook.MainActivity paused=false}
11-14 14:19:29.429: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:29.429: I/PackageManager(146): Package com.example.facebook codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.facebook-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.facebook-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
11-14 14:19:29.479: W/InputMethodManagerService(146): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1339 uid 10054
11-14 14:19:29.559: I/PackageManager(146): Running dexopt on: com.example.facebook
11-14 14:19:30.549: D/dalvikvm(1369): DexOpt: load 142ms, verify+opt 469ms, 833796 bytes
11-14 14:19:30.569: W/PackageManager(146): Code path for pkg : com.example.facebook changing from /data/app/com.example.facebook-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.facebook-2.apk
11-14 14:19:30.569: W/PackageManager(146): Resource path for pkg : com.example.facebook changing from /data/app/com.example.facebook-1.apk to /data/app/com.example.facebook-2.apk
11-14 14:19:30.579: I/ActivityManager(146): Force stopping package com.example.facebook uid=10054
11-14 14:19:30.659: D/dalvikvm(146): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 681K, 9% free 9626K/10567K, paused 81ms, total 81ms
11-14 14:19:30.759: D/PackageManager(146): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.facebook-2.apk
11-14 14:19:30.839: I/ActivityManager(146): Force stopping package com.example.facebook uid=10054
11-14 14:19:30.849: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-14 14:19:30.920: D/dalvikvm(330): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-14 14:19:30.949: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_EXPLICIT freed 185K, 36% free 9272K/14471K, paused 7ms+14ms, total 92ms
11-14 14:19:31.009: D/dalvikvm(146): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-14 14:19:31.059: I/InputReader(146): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
11-14 14:19:31.170: D/dalvikvm(146): GC_EXPLICIT freed 475K, 11% free 9461K/10567K, paused 38ms+10ms, total 163ms
11-14 14:19:31.189: D/PackageManager(146): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
11-14 14:19:31.210: D/PackageManager(146): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
11-14 14:19:31.219: D/BackupManagerService(146): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.facebook flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
11-14 14:19:31.219: D/dalvikvm(330): GC_EXPLICIT freed 169K, 6% free 6320K/6663K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 293ms
11-14 14:19:31.259: D/PackageManager(146): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
11-14 14:19:31.279: D/PackageManager(146): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
11-14 14:19:31.299: D/BackupManagerService(146): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.facebook flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
11-14 14:19:31.299: V/BackupManagerService(146): removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10054 #1
11-14 14:19:31.310: I/InputReader(146): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
11-14 14:19:31.429: V/BackupManagerService(146): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
11-14 14:19:31.699: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 259 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:31.909: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:32.179: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1331K, 38% free 9017K/14471K, paused 29ms+9ms, total 116ms
11-14 14:19:32.179: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 62ms
11-14 14:19:32.179: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 80ms
11-14 14:19:32.439: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 34% free 9614K/14471K, paused 30ms+7ms, total 84ms
11-14 14:19:32.439: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 54ms
11-14 14:19:32.439: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 70ms
11-14 14:19:32.449: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 60ms
11-14 14:19:32.449: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 67ms
11-14 14:19:32.639: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 929K, 37% free 9199K/14471K, paused 41ms, total 47ms
11-14 14:19:32.649: I/dalvikvm-heap(263): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.257MB for 1286224-byte allocation
11-14 14:19:32.779: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 28% free 10448K/14471K, paused 128ms, total 134ms
11-14 14:19:32.920: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 27% free 10681K/14471K, paused 16ms+38ms, total 134ms
11-14 14:19:32.969: D/dalvikvm(146): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-14 14:19:33.269: W/InputMethodManagerService(146): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
11-14 14:19:33.349: W/RecognitionManagerService(146): no available voice recognition services found
11-14 14:19:33.899: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3879K, 43% free 8263K/14471K, paused 34ms+10ms, total 114ms
11-14 14:19:33.949: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:34.249: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 40% free 8702K/14471K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
11-14 14:19:34.369: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 327K, 38% free 8973K/14471K, paused 39ms, total 42ms
11-14 14:19:34.619: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 767K, 37% free 9191K/14471K, paused 39ms+6ms, total 94ms
11-14 14:19:34.619: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms
11-14 14:19:34.619: D/dalvikvm(263): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 47ms
11-14 14:19:34.789: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 232K, 37% free 9257K/14471K, paused 49ms, total 55ms
11-14 14:19:34.799: I/dalvikvm-heap(263): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.314MB for 1286224-byte allocation
11-14 14:19:34.879: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 28% free 10509K/14471K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
11-14 14:19:35.009: D/dalvikvm(263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 26K, 28% free 10510K/14471K, paused 27ms+7ms, total 132ms
11-14 14:19:35.149: D/dalvikvm(146): GC_EXPLICIT freed 520K, 10% free 9550K/10567K, paused 116ms+516ms, total 2113ms
11-14 14:19:35.159: D/AndroidRuntime(1359): Shutting down VM
11-14 14:19:35.179: D/dalvikvm(1359): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 459K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 10ms
11-14 14:19:35.179: D/jdwp(1359): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-14 14:19:35.179: D/dalvikvm(1359): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-14 14:19:35.189: I/AndroidRuntime(1359): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
11-14 14:19:35.759: D/AndroidRuntime(1377): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-14 14:19:35.759: D/AndroidRuntime(1377): CheckJNI is ON
11-14 14:19:35.799: D/dalvikvm(1377): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:35.799: D/dalvikvm(1377): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:35.829: D/dalvikvm(1377): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:35.829: D/dalvikvm(1377): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-14 14:19:36.509: D/AndroidRuntime(1377): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-14 14:19:36.529: I/ActivityManager(146): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.facebook/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 1377
11-14 14:19:36.539: W/WindowManager(146): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21020
11-14 14:19:36.579: D/AndroidRuntime(1377): Shutting down VM
11-14 14:19:36.590: D/dalvikvm(1377): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 489K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 11ms
11-14 14:19:36.590: D/jdwp(1377): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
11-14 14:19:36.590: D/dalvikvm(1377): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-14 14:19:36.599: I/AndroidRuntime(1377): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
11-14 14:19:36.609: D/dalvikvm(1387): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-14 14:19:36.630: I/ActivityManager(146): Start proc com.example.facebook for activity com.example.facebook/.MainActivity: pid=1387 uid=10054 gids={3003, 1028}
11-14 14:19:36.630: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:36.929: E/Trace(1387): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-14 14:19:38.359: D/dalvikvm(1387): GC_CONCURRENT freed 284K, 6% free 6199K/6535K, paused 72ms+84ms, total 206ms
11-14 14:19:39.219: I/Choreographer(1387): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.239: D/gralloc_goldfish(1387): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-14 14:19:39.279: I/ActivityManager(146): Displayed com.example.facebook/.MainActivity: +2s710ms
11-14 14:19:39.443: I/Choreographer(1387): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.449: I/Choreographer(263): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.459: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.551: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.679: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.759: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:39.852: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.122: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.239: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.319: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.391: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.471: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.568: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.681: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:19:41.761: I/Choreographer(146): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 14:20:00.092: I/Choreographer(217): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

thanks for anyone can help.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

Comment: Not this log buddy. The log where you see your results from the facebook query.

Comment: that's all I have in Log cat when I run the Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You are choosing the wrong `tags` to make the query for getting the User's location.

If you are using the Graph API, then the `tag` in question is: **location**. The `user_location` that you have used, is a *permission*.

Second, and perhaps more importantly, you are choosing these permissions: `{"email", "publish_stream"}`

To get the User's `birthday` and his / her `location` you will also need these permissions:
For the User logged into your app: `user_location`. And for getting the logged in user's friends location: `friends_location`

Similarly, for the `birthday`, you will need these permissions: `user_birthday` for the logged in user and `friends_birthday` for the logged in user's friends.

Take a look at the list of available fields for querying and getting results here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

And for a list of all permissions, take a look at this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

**EDIT 2:**

Removing the earlier FQL suggestion and providing an alternate.

```
String testURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,birthday,email,location&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

try {
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(testURL);
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

    if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

        JSONArray JAUserInfo = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < JAUserInfo.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JOUserInfo = JAUserInfo.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e("USER DETAILS", JOUserInfo.toString());
                    if (JOUserInfo.has("location") {
                        JSONObject JOLocation = JOUserInfo.optJSONObject("location");
                        String location = JOLocation.getString("name");
                    }

        }

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

**NOTE:** You need to provide an Access Token in this query. Without that, this will without doubt, fail. Just change the **YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN** in the `String testURL` to your Access Token.